# How to change a background image of a button in Android without knowing the image name earlier?

Tags: java, android

I have some image files in drawable folder. The name of the images are like button1, button2, button3......There is also a count variable which increases by one whenever a button is clicked.What I want to do is that whenever someone click on a button image of that button should change to the image corresponding to the current value of count.

I tried

```
buttons[0][0].setBackground(R.drawable.button+count);
```

But it is not working

Comment: please post your entire code so that we can have a look

Comment: You can hashmap the drawables with the counts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access it directly. You'll have to get the resource using its name:

```
private Drawable getDrawableResourceByName(int count) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("button" + String.valueOf(count), "drawable", packageName);
    return getResources().getDrawable(resId);
}
```

Then use it as:

```
buttons[0][0].setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawableResourceByName(count)); //setBackground() only works with drawables from API 16
```